# PHP file_get_contents then replace string in a file

Tags: php

I am using this

```
file_put_contents('/usr/local/file.cfg', str_replace(  "mypassword:=$one", "mypassword:=$two",  file_get_contents('/usr/local/file.cfg')    ));
```

to change   mypassword:= value from value $one to value $two

BUT , inside file /usr/local/file.cfg I have also arx_mypassword=arx_value which is changed too using the command above, but I do not want change it .

Can I change mypassword value without changing arx_mypassword value too ?

Thank you

Comment: Sure, use `preg_replace` instead for more control. In particular, the `^` and `$` special characters will permit you to include the start/end of the line in your pattern.

Comment: so can I use this

file_put_contents('/usr/local/file.cfg', preg_replace(  "^mypassword:=one", "mypassword:=two",  file_get_contents('/usr/local/file.cfg') ));

is it correct ?

Comment: Not quite. Read the docs on `preg_replace`. Your pattern needs delineators, but you're close.

Comment: file_put_contents('/usr/local/file.cfg', preg_replace( "/^mypassword:=one/", "mypassword:=two", file_get_contents('/usr/local/file.cfg') ));

is it correct ?

Comment: Maybe. Give it a try. I don't know the exact format of your config files.

Comment: I tried it does not work because one is  $one

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. If `$one` is what you're trying to replace, a) say so in your question and b) look up escaping special characters in the `preg_replace` docs.

Comment: Provide a reproducible example. https://eval.in/639697 Since `mypassword` != `arx_password` you shouldn't be having that replaced.

Comment: Sorry chris85 , it's arx_mypassword .